# Simple name and qualified name

Tags: java

I'm reading [JLS 8 and in Chapter 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html) is written:

> A qualified name N.x may be used to refer to a member of a package or
>   reference type, where N is a simple or qualified name and x is an
>   identifier. If N names a package, then x is a member of that package,
>   which is either a class or interface type or a subpackage. If N names
>   a reference type or a variable of a reference type, then x names a
>   member of that type, which is either a class, an interface, a field,
>   or a method.

so I could imagine that having this:

```
class C
{
    public int n;
}

int j;
C c = new C(); 
j = 11;  
c.n = 11;
```

`j` is a simple name while `c.n` is a qualified name.

However in [6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2) things get complicated. Is given this code:

```
class Test { 
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
 Class c = System.out.getClass(); 
 System.out.println(c.toString().length() + 
 args[0].length() + args.length); 
 } 
}
```

and after is said:

> The occurrence of length in args.length is a name because args.length
>   is a qualified name (§6.5.6.2) and not a field access expression
>   (§15.11). A field access expression, as well as a method invocation
>   expression, a method reference expression, and a qualified class
>   instance creation expression, uses an identifier rather than a name to
>   denote the member of interest. Thus, the occurrence of length in
>   args[0].length() is not a name, but rather an identifier appearing in
>   a method invocation expression.

so I think I understand that not all expressions are qualified names and
even my expression `c.n`

Honestly I can not understand the distinction can anyone help me?

Comment: It'd be easier to read the sections of the spec you're referring to if you were to add some links.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to understand here? Don't get me wrong, I'm not knocking the question, I love reading JLS to find things like this out, but I have to say, I'm struggling with the distinction too - and I think it might help to understand the specific context of the problem at hand rather than the generality of the spec.

Answer (score 5):

In your exemple:

`int j;` is a simple expression name because it consists of a single Identifier

For qualified example, from the [JLS 6.5.6.2. Qualified Expression Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.2) :

> If an expression name is of the form Q.Id, then Q has already been classified as a package name, a type name, or an expression name.

In `c.n`, `c` is an expression name, `n` is a field of class T (class C in your exemple). So `c.n` is a qualified expression name.

`args.length` is also a qualified expression name. `args` is an array so it's not really a specific class (no .class file but [run-time type signature is generated though](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8)) but it's still an object with a field named `length`.

`args[0].length()` is not a qualified name because `length()` is not a member of the class. It's an identifier of a method invocation expression.

```
MethodInvocation:
  MethodName ( [ArgumentList] )
  TypeName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
  ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
  Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
  super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
  TypeName . super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )

ArgumentList:
  Expression {, Expression}
```

Cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

Comment: Isn't OP asking about the `args.length`, rather than the `args[0].length()` case,though?

Comment: @AndyTurner In the question, the OP quoted the sentence from the JLS saying that args.length is a qualified name. I think it was clear but I'll add this the answer too :)

Comment: Isn't `j` in `int j;` simply an identifier instead of a "simple name" as you state?